# GTK focus-out-event

Tags: python, gtk, popupwindow, glade

I am showing a user a popup menu when they right click.

According to the popup behaviour, I want to destroy the popup when it looses focus(when user clicks outside the popup window). For that I tried to connect the popup window to "**focus-out-event**", using Glade. But for some reason, that event is not getting fired. I tried to print something on the terminal when the event is fired, but nothing gets printed.

I am new to Python and GTK, and now I have no clue how to proceed further.

```
#handler to catch the focus out event
def on_popup_menu_add_attachment_focus_out_event(self, *args):
    print("Destroying the popup.....")
```

**focus-out-signal and its handler**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just changed the Type as Top Level and it worked!